# Mostrar todos los mensajes en un filtro de checkboxes HTML, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web

Tengo la siguiente duda, me estoy basando en este ejemplo para crear mi propio filtro con checkboxes, pero no se de que manera puedo añadir el checkbox que muestre todos mis mensajes y que al momento que se oprima otro checkbox,se le quite el cheked al checkbox de ¨Todos¨

Este es el HTML en el que me estoy basando:

```
<div class="tags">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" rel="todos" />
        Todos
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" rel="arts" />
        Arts
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" rel="computers" />
        Computers
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" rel="health" />
        Health
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" rel="video-games" />
        Video Games
    </label>
</div>
<ul class="results">
    <li class="arts computers">Result 1</li>
    <li class="video-games">Result 2</li>
    <li class="computers health video-games">Result 3</li>
    <li class="arts video-games">Result 4</li>
</ul>
```

y este es el JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.results > li').hide();

        $('div.tags').find('input:checkbox').live('click', function () {
            $('.results > li').hide();
            $('div.tags').find('input:checked').each(function () {
                $('.results > li.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
            });
        });
    });
```

Espero puedan ayudarme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supongo que con el atributo `rel` te quieres referir al `id`. Además de desmarcar *todos* al pulsar otro *check*, puse que si se marca *todos* se vuelvan a desmarcar los otros *checks*

```js
setTimeout(function(){
$('.results > li').hide();
}, 1);

$(".tags input").on("click", function(){
  if($(this).attr("id") == "todos"){
    $("#arts, #computers, #health, #video-games").prop('checked', false);
    filtrar(true);
  }else{
    $("#todos").prop('checked', false);
    filtrar(false);
  }
});

function filtrar(e){
  if(e){
  $(".results li").each(function(){
    $(this).show();
    });
  }else{
    $('.results li').hide();
    $('.tags').find('input:checked').each(function () {
       $('.results li.' + $(this).attr('id')).show();
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tags">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="todos" />
        Todos
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="arts" />
        Arts
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="computers" />
        Computers
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="health" />
        Health
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="video-games" />
        Video Games
    </label>
</div>
<ul class="results">
    <li class="arts">Result Arts</li>
    <li class="computers">Result Computers</li>
    <li class="health">Result Health</li>
    <li class="video-games">Result Video-games</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: pero igual esto me permitirá seguir filtrando a como lo estoy haciendo?

Comment: @Pony94 edité un poco el código para que ocurra el filtrado. Cambié las clases de la lista de resultados. Espero que sea lo que querías. (la función .live() está obsoleta)

Comment: cosa rara es que cuando intento usarlo no funciona en mi lap

Comment: E hice todos los cambios u,u

Comment: Colocaste una versión más nueva de jquery?

Comment: Nop es la misma, asi esta mi codigo

Comment: copie & pegue tal & como pusiste el script & el html

Comment: reemplazando todo lo que tenia antes